# Can not print out the argv[] values using std::cout in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, cout, argv

This is my first question on the site even though i have been coming here for reference for quite some time now. I understand that argv[0] stores the name of the program and the rest of the commandline arguements are stored in teh remaining argv[k] slots. I also understand that std::cout treats a character pointer like a null terminated string and prints the string out. Below is my program.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    cout << argv[0] << " ";
    cout << argv[1] ;

    return 0;
}
```

According to all the other programs I have seen over my internet search in the issue, this program should printout two strings viz. name of the program and the commandline arguement. The console window shows

0010418c 001048d6

I believe these are the pointers to argv[0] and argv[1] resp.
The only commandline arguement I have is "nanddumpgood.bin" which goes in argv[1] and shows the strings correctly if I mouseover the argv[] arrays while debugging.

Whis is this happening? What am I doing wrong? I understand, arrays decay to pointers in special cases? Is this a case where it doesnt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I also understand that `std::cout` treats a character pointer like a null terminated string and prints the string out.

That's *mostly* correct.  It works for `char*`, but not other types of characters.  Which is exactly the problem.  You have a `_TCHAR*`, which IS `char*` on an ANSI build but not on a Unicode build, so instead of getting the special string behavior, you get the default pointer behavior.

> I understand, arrays decay to pointers in special cases? Is this a case where it doesnt?

`argv` is an array, but neither `argv[0]` nor `argv[1]` are arrays, they are both pointers.  Decay is not a factor here.

The simplest fix is to use `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` so that you get non-Unicode strings for the command-line arguments.  I'm recommending this, rather than switching to `wcout`, because it's much more compatible with other code you find on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Use `wcout` for Unicode strings.

Comment: If he's using `wcout`, he might as well change the arguments to `wchar_t`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are compiling your application with the unicode compiler switch which treats all TCHAR as wchar_t. Therefore cout treats argv as an int.

Write instead

```
wcout << argv[0] << L" "; 
wcout << argv[1] ;
```

or change to `Use Multi-byte character` set in the Project settings/General.

Comment: No, it's doesn't treat `argv` as an int.  It's a pointer, but not a `char*`.

Comment: I was using Visual Studio 2010. I guess I forgot to mention. Thanks for the clarification Ben.