# `cout << argv[0]` returning hex value?

Tags: c++, iostream, tchar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can not print out the argv[] values using std::cout in VC++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096369/can-not-print-out-the-argv-values-using-stdcout-in-vc)

Code:

```
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << argv[0] << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, a standard Win32 console application.
The confusing part is, the value of `argv[0]` is output as `00035B88`.
This is being (AFAIK) run with no command-line options so `argv[]` should not have a value yet. (or is this the problem?)

However, `argv[]` is declared as a pointer (`_TCHAR*`) and I heard that `cout` will print the address of pointers. Is this the case? If so, how can I print/use the value of `argv`?

Comment: The second arg of main is a char** (or char * []) so you are outputing the address not the value. argv[0] is a pointer

Comment: My guess is that your settings have `_TCHAR` defined as a `wchar_t` instead of a normal `char`.

Comment: Here's your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096369/can-not-print-out-the-argv-values-using-stdcout-in-vc

Answer (score 6):

`_TCHAR` is a wide-character type if the executable was built with the Unicode option. `cout` can't handle wide characters, so instead of turning it into a `char *` and printing out a string, it (effectively) uses the default `void *` printer which prints out the address of the string.

Use `wcout` instead.

Comment: oh, so `_T` is for wide characters in Windows.. Oh God, whyyy....

Comment: `_T` means "text", and its interpretation depends on the definition of the `_UNICODE` macro (if defined, it's `wchar_t`, else it is `char`). This also determines whether you get the 'A' (narrow) or 'W' (wide) versions of certain functions. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194799.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. The first array entry in argv (ie. argv[0]) is, if I remember right, the name of the executable. So it might be printing the address of the first character in a c style character array. Try this:

```
cout << (char *)argv[0] << endl;
```

Comment: I can't comment on other peoples posts yet, so I'll put it here: TCHAR will change whether the build is a unicode build or not. But it sounds like wcout will fix the problem.

Comment: Rather, more specifically, `_TCHAR`'s definition is dependent on `_UNICODE`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `project settings->General`. Go to `"Character encoding"` and select `"multibyte character set"`. And change your `_tmain()` to `main()`. Now it will print your characters.